# Is there a way to set a path specific to a user ...?

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, user-management

I have a lab of developers that jump from workstation to workstation due to development and Debugging in a live production state (Robotics).  I have one developer who is wanting to test a new compiler and wants his path to be modified upon login no matter which workstation he is on.

Basically, can I set his specific path variable to be added to his path to the compilers \bin directory located with his home user folder that's always mapped to U:.

The server is running Windows Server 2008 using AD, Terminal services is not running on this box.  All workstations are Windows XP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user can use the "Environment Varaibles" dialog in the "Advanced" tab of "Comptuer Properties" to create a PATH variable. Anything they add there will be concatenated to the end of the system-wide PATH.

If your user has roaming user profiles then you're all set. If not, you could script something to add the necessary entry to the user's "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment" registry during logon.

(A user can't use the traditional "SETX" utility to modify the global environment unless they're an Administrator. If they are, then you could use that, too, but I am loathe to encourage anyone to allow users to have Administrator rights. You shouldn't use an Administrator-level account for day-to-day computing activities ever.)

Comment: Thank You, once I set him to roaming profile he was able to compile on several workstations.

Comment: Sounds good! Glad I could help.